# How to get key from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [];
 arr["EMP"] = [{"emp_id":"EmpId","AttDate":"AttDate","Status":"AttStatus"}];
```

how to retrieve variables like emp_id, AttDate, Status in the above array?

Comment: Arrays don't have keys in JavaScript. Objects have keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [];
arr["EMP"] = [{"emp_id":"EmpId","AttDate":"AttDate","Status":"AttStatus"}];
x = arr["EMP"][0];
Object.keys(x);
```

Output:  ["emp_id", "AttDate", "Status"]

You can get all the keys in an array by using Object.keys(Obj)

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve like this for above array

```
   var emp_id = arr.EMP[0].emp_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Array don't have keys in javascript. if you want to get indexing you can get like this

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const iterator = array1.keys();

for (const key of iterator) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

You will get this result
// 0 1 2

Answer (score 0):

Use the destructuring.

```js
var arr = [];
arr["EMP"] = [{ emp_id: "EmpId", AttDate: "AttDate", Status: "AttStatus" }];

const { EMP: [{ emp_id, AttDate, Status }] } = arr;

console.log(emp_id, AttDate, Status);

// Alternative way
// const [{ emp_id, AttDate, Status }] = arr["EMP"];
// console.log(emp_id, AttDate, Status);
```